# Is it possible to create a virtual env with specific Julia version in it?

Tags: package, julia

I have installed Julia `v1.7.0`. Now I want to create a new virtual environment that contains a specific version of Julia(e.g. `v1.7.3`); When I activate the new environment, I want to run my code by the particular version of Julia(contained/assigned in/to the new env. in this example, `v1.7.3`) and packages. Is it possible to do this? or I shall download the Julia `v1.7.3` from the official website and create a new env using that?

I know I can create a new virtual environment [in this way](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/environments/#Creating-your-own-projects). But this explanation hasn't provided information about my specific question, so I had no choice except to ask it here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is to have a common shared named environment for `major.minor` version. By default, this is usually `~/.julia/environments/1.7`.

As of Julia 1.7, you can create a shared named environment by prefixing the project name with an `@` or by providing the `--shared` option to activate.

```
(@v1.7) pkg> st
      Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  [295af30f] Revise v3.3.1

(@v1.7) pkg> activate @1.7.3
  Activating new project at `~/.julia/environments/1.7.3`

(@1.7.3) pkg> st
      Status `~/.julia/environments/1.7.3/Project.toml` (empty project)

(@1.7.3) pkg> activate --shared 1.7.3
      Status `~/.julia/environments/1.7.3/Project.toml` (empty project)
```

Also you can always just change the current working directory to another folder and turn that into an environment.

Note that environments stack. By default your `@1.7` environment will still provide a base for your `@1.7.3` environment. You can observe this by running `Base.load_path()`. You can create a different environment stacking by manipulating `LOAD_PATH`:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/constants/#Base.LOAD_PATH

You can also manipulate this using environment variables.
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/

For example, this is done in the conda-forge package for Julia. In this case, the entire Julia depot is relocated into the conda environment. For an example of how to manipulate the current `JULIA_PROJECT`, `JULIA_LOAD_PATH`, and `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` see below.

https://github.com/conda-forge/julia-feedstock/blob/f9e44873689d69a87a5eaa544e7aaea6feebc50c/recipe/scripts/activate.sh#L12

Answer (score 0):

Julia environments do not contain the julia version that you'd like to run them with - the version bounds written to the `Project.toml` is just a bound on *compatibility* of the code written inside of the environment, specifying what minimum julia versions the code of the environment will work with. You will still need to have an appropriate julia version installed & run the code in the environment with it.

`Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml` are only there to give a reproducible state of the environment, with version bounded dependencies, julia itself being one of them. In particular, an environment does not contain code and/or binary artifacts of all its dependencies.